# Removing an Element in an Array in Ruby(Without using premade methods)

Tags: arrays, ruby, pointers

I have the following array
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
I am now trying to delete an element from the array,lets say a[4]. I know to do this you can use ruby methods such as pop ,however, for this task I am trying to do it manually.

I had tried using the following:
a[4] = nil
However, this just results in the value at this index being replaced by nil instead of removing the pointer to this value completely (ie: a.length still considers nil a value in the array).

As I see there are many questions regarding my question, I will emphasize that what I am trying to do is accomplish the methods such as pop myself. So far all I could come up with is copying all contents of the array to a new array(with 1 less length) and returning that. I am not sure if that is how pop works internally or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by doing it 'manually' ?

Comment: I really can´t understand why you are doing it, but you can check how it is done in ruby sources: https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Comment: You know that `a[4] = nil` is actually a [method call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), right? So is `a.length` for that matter. What exactly do you mean by "without using premade methods"?

Comment: I realize that a.length is a method call but how is a[4] = nil a method call? I am using a.length as it does not have anything to do with the actual removal of the element. When i say no methods i mean for the actual removal of an element from the array. So far the only way I could come up with is making a method and copy all the contents of the array to another array with 1 less element. Wondering if there is a better way to do this

Comment: `a[4] = nil` is a call to the [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method of [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D). It's syntactically equivalent to `a.[]=(4, nil)`.

Comment: Are you trying to remove *any arbitrary element* or is it just the *last element*?  This is unclear in your question.  There's no reasoning behind *why* you don't want to use "premade methods", nor what you actually mean by that, so it's virtually impossible to answer this question.

Comment: I wish to remove an arbitrary element. The element need not be last or first (it can be a[2] as well for instance). I only used pop as an example. As stated above, I've accomplished this using a method that copys all contents to a new array minus whatever elements the user wants to remove(thus shifting all elements in the required positions), however, I am not sure if this is the best way to do this (that is if a copy of an array is necessary).

Comment: @jonathanrz The code provided by Mr_Sudaca seems to have answered my question but I also have looked at the source files which has also helped me a ton. So thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe...

```
class Array
   def custom_remove(position)
     array = []
     each_with_index do |elm, index|
       next if position == index
       array << elm
     end
     array
   end
end


1.9.3-p545 :035 > class Array
1.9.3-p545 :036?>          def custom_remove(position)
1.9.3-p545 :037?>              array = []
1.9.3-p545 :038?>              each_with_index do |elm, index|
1.9.3-p545 :039 >                    next if position == index
1.9.3-p545 :040?>                  array << elm
1.9.3-p545 :041?>                end
1.9.3-p545 :042?>              array
1.9.3-p545 :043?>            end
1.9.3-p545 :044?>       end
 => nil
1.9.3-p545 :045 > a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1.9.3-p545 :046 > a.custom_remove(4)
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: It also contains several Ruby methods, `each_with_index` being just one example: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index

Comment: Of course, it's ruby, so everything it's made at the top of it. Maybe OP wanted to recreate a common ruby method without actually using it, like map, inject or collect....

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it in Ruby without using Ruby methods.

EDIT (more detail):
Ruby is a [scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) written in C. To be fair, I and many others, I'm sure, understand what you meant but, strictly speaking, it's quite a paradoxical question; I'm sure by 'pre-made' methods you meant things like `#pop` and `#compact` but how would you achieve your goal without using *any* Ruby methods?!

Comment: I am not sure, ruby is a scripted language, so you can do anything that the language do. Why you think it is not possible?

Comment: @jonathanrz: Ruby is an object-oriented language. In an object-oriented language, pretty much the only thing you can do is call methods, that's how anything gets done. Since the OP disallowed calling methods, there is literally *nothing* at all you can do (except assigning and dereferencing variables and a small number of keywords).

Comment: The question is vague, but I doubt very much that you have answered it. An upvote? Oh, my!

Comment: @JörgWMittag you can call private method with send: http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/

Comment: @jonathanrz: I don't understand what this has to do with the question. The OP said calling methods is not allowed. Period. If you call a method with `send`, you are still calling a method, in fact, you are calling *two* methods, since you are additionally calling `send` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can still use the

```
a[4]=nil
```

but also do:

```
b = a.compact
```

It will return a new array without the nil.

Comment: Did you read the question? He said he don´t want to use ruby methods.

Comment: That does work,however,my issue is that the Array.length function will still hold an array length of 5,even when the last element(nil) has been removed. My question doesn't really relate to the nil removal itself but more about how many elements are in the array. Ie: by removing a[4] I would want the a.length to = 4 rather then 5.

Comment: If you use ``compact`` then the length will update as well, it should not report 5 .``[1,2,3,4,nil].compact.length`` returns ``4``.

Comment: Interesting as I just tried it and it is still returning 5.

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing. But this only simply fixes the problem for that instance of the array. If I did the same such as a.compact then a.length it is still 5

Comment: Use ``a.compact!``

Comment: The OP said you are not allowed to call methods. However, you are calling the `Array#[]=` method and the `Array#compact` method.

Comment: Of course this solution fails if  `nil` is a valid possible value for other elements.

Comment: So according to this my answer help you to understand :)